# How does package-info.java work?

Tags: java, jaxb

When I generate Java files from XML Schema using JAXB, package-info.java file is generated.

What is this file for? and how does it work?

Especially, this file contains annotation like below.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://searchrequest")
```

What does this mean? 
I doubt this does something with javadoc or Eclipse Juno.

This should be something specific with JAXB, isn't it?

Comment: Oh! sorry, but it didn't appear when I searched before posting this question. Should I remove this question?

Comment: Yes, if the answer to the duplicate question also solved your problem, you should delete this one to avoid "diluting the answer pool" (a phrase I just made up).

Comment: OK, but can anyone provide me some hint about the part of annotation? It also does part of question.

Comment: Please, any information about annotation? @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://searchrequest")

Answer (score 12):

The `package-info.java` is a Java file that can be added to any Java source package.  Its purpose is to provide a home for package level documentation and package level annotations.

It Can contain a `package declaration`, `package annotations`, `package comments` and `Javadoc tags`. This file is generally preferred over `package.html`.

For more information visit:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#packagecomment

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/